# php getting text from a html file

Tags: php

I have a php file that reads a html documents on another website and stores the data in a variable called "$content"

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

what I can't figure out is the best way to get this string of text from the $content/html

```
 <b>111 players online</b>
```

I was going to try and get the text inbetween the   tags but it's a rather large html file and there's hundreds of  tags

I then looked into using html DOM but couldn't figure out how to determine the elementId or tagName

any help would be much appreciated

oh and for anyone wondering the website Im trying to get the players online text for is -

```
view-source:http://www.pkhonor.net/
```

Comment: Why not try `file_get_contents` which returns a string representation of your HTML file.  Also, are you using a REGEX to scan the string (your html) for the pattern? `<b>111 players online</b>` ?

Comment: What are the contents of the variable `$content` ? also, do you need to really use `CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER` ? I would think this setting is not necessary.

Comment: because fopen() is disabled on my webhost (there pretty strict and are overly cautious)

as for REGEX im not entirely sure on how I would scan for the string when the number "111" is constantly changing ?

Comment: You would scan for text between the `<b>` tags, but in the answer below the method `getElementsByTagName` should do the trick. I upvoted the answer from @hellsgate because I LEARNED something today! Awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPs [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is what you'd want to use here, specifically the [loadHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) method to parse the HTML into an object. You can then grab all of the `<b>` elements into an array which you can then loop through:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);

$bolds = $doc->getElementsByTagName('b');
if ($nodes->length > 0) {
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        echo $node->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

[DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)

Comment: ^ this worked perfectly, thanks for all the help guys :)

Comment: @MateiMihai sorry I forgot to do it :P